# How to select data from partitioned tables into partitioned destination tables?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

In Google Big Query, it's straightforward to select across all partitioned tables using wildcard operators. For example, I could select all rows from date partitioned tables with something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `project.dataset.table_name__*`;
```

That would give me all results from `project.dataset.table_name__20161127`,
`project.dataset.table_name__20161128`, `project.dataset.table_name__20161129`, etc.

What I don't understand is how to specify partitioned destination tables. How do I ensure that result set is written to, as an example, `project.dataset.dest-table__20161127`,
`project.dataset.table-name__20161128`, `project.dataset.table-name__20161129`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: These are dated tables, not partitioned tables. They are multiple tables, and a query can only have one destination table, so you wont' be able to write the result into many of them.

You can take a look at date-partitioned tables at https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables. We only allow writing the result into one partition now, but we're working on writing to multiple partitions.

Comment: @Hua Zhang : any update on writing to multiple partitions ? Is that feature still being worked on ?

Comment: We're close to complete the feature, and hope to release it by end of year.